# concatenate the results of a Linq query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am wondering if anyone can help me, the issue I have is that I cant return the results in a concatenate string using Linq. The query works fine the issue is how to concatenate the results as string, string so forth as there can be many hash tags

```
var contacttag = (from HE in HashTagEntities
join t in Accounts on HE.Parentid equals t.id
where HE.ParentId == 3 &&
t.AccountName == "Test"
from tag in HashTags
where HE.HashTagid == tag.HOCODE
select new { tag.HashTagText }).Select(x => x.HashTagText.ToString());
```

If anyone could help I would be grateful I am getting a error below:

"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: I think if you cast the query `(from HE in ... tag.HashTagText })` to `IEnumerable<T>` (where `T` is the type of `HashTagText`), it should work. That ought to avoid going through the Entities extension methods. If that doesn't work, you might have to use `ToList()` before the `Select()` to get out of the Entities handling of the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already selecting a collection of strings with `select new { tag.HashTagText }`, so there is no need to select them again or call `.ToString()` on them.

You should be able to simply use `string.Join()`:

```
var contacttag = from HE in HashTagEntities
                 join t in Accounts on HE.Parentid equals t.id
                 where HE.ParentId == 3 &&
                 t.AccountName == "Test"
                 from tag in HashTags
                 where HE.HashTagid == tag.HOCODE
                 select tag.HashTagText;

var tags = string.Concat(contacttag);
```

or in .NET 3.5:

```
var tags = string.Concat(contacttag.ToArray());
```

I can't see any reason why one would insist on doing this in a single statement, but it can be done:

```
var tags = string.Concat((from HE in HashTagEntities
                 join t in Accounts on HE.Parentid equals t.id
                 where HE.ParentId == 3 &&
                 t.AccountName == "Test"
                 from tag in HashTags
                 where HE.HashTagid == tag.HOCODE
                 select tag.HashTagText).ToArray());
```

Comment: Could it be done in the one query, I have tried var tags = string.Join("", THE FULL QUERY TO ARRAY ); and I got Linq does not recognize string.Join

Comment: @BillyJoe - You mean in one line? Personally i think it is more readable if you first define the query, and then concatenate the resulting strings.

Comment: I reason why I asked was because, this one part of a query which is filling a list for each customer of many customers. I wanted to keep the questain straight forward and I tried not to over complicate it.

Comment: @BillyJoe As Martin says, I don't know why you would insist on doing this in one line, but it can be done. Please see my update.

Comment: The error I am getting is Message "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression." string

Comment: @BillyJoe Please try the versions above with `.ToArray()`. I've also changed them from `string.Join` to `string.Concat`, since the latter should be sufficient if you just want to concatenate them.

Comment: @JLRishe Tried that I am getting this :{"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Concat(System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."} also tried ` .ToArray().Aggregate((now, nextitem) => now + ", " + nextitem) `

Comment: Are you trying to perform this concatenation and then use it _inside_ yet another query? That would explain why you keep getting errors.

Comment: @JLRishe it is inside another query, works outside but not inside

Comment: @BillyJoe That's a bit of crucial information you didn't include in your question. Since this one has already been answered, I suggest opening a new question to take on that additional requirement.

Comment: How would one approach solving this.?

Comment: @BillyJoe If you open up a new question with all the relevant details, I'm sure there are people who would be happy to help you, including myself.